# Worksheet named "Control" doesn't exist

Tags: vba, excel

I have in my workbook a worksheet named Control and in my vba functions it isn't recognized. Why?

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    On Error GoTo handler

    Set m_connectionSettingsSheet = GetWorkSheet("Control")

    Userid = ValueOfNameInSheetStartingWith("userName", "Control")
    Pwd = PasswordForm.TextBox1.value

    'Pwd = ValueOfNameInSheetStartingWith("password", "Control")

    'ServerBaseAddress = m_connectionSettingsSheet.Range("ServerBaseAddress").value
    ServerBaseAddress = ValueOfNameInSheetStartingWith("ServerBaseAddress", "Control")
```

And in class ImporterSetup I get the field username, password and url from the cells of the worksheet "Control". This is a Import for Excel from Jira

The function to verify if the worksheet exists is this:

```
Private Function GetWorkSheet(workSheetName As String) As Worksheet

 If WorksheetExists(workSheetName) Then 
     GetWorkSheet = WorksheetExists(workSheetName) 
 Else
     MsgBox ("Must have the worksheet named " & workSheetName) 
 End If 

End Function 

Private Function WorksheetExists(ByVal workSheetName As String) As Boolean    
   IsExists = False 

   For Each ws In Worksheets 
      If workSheetName = ws.name Then 
         IsExists = True 
         Exit Function
      End If 
   Next ws 

End Function
```

Comment: Make sure the actual sheet does not have unprintable characters either before or after.

Comment: nop.. and the function to verify if the worksheet exists is this:
Private Function GetWorkSheet(workSheetName As String) As Worksheet
    If WorksheetExists(workSheetName) Then
        GetWorkSheet = WorksheetExists(workSheetName)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Must have the worksheet named " & workSheetName)
    End If
End Function

Private Function WorksheetExists(ByVal workSheetName As String) As Boolean
  IsExists = False
      For Each ws In Worksheets
        If workSheetName = ws.name Then
          IsExists = True
          Exit Function
        End If
      Next ws
End Function

Comment: please edit your original post with the code.  Comments make it hard to read.

Comment: Is GetWorkSheet another function you wrote? If so, post that in your question. Also post "ValueOfNameInSheetStartingWith".

Comment: Stick `Option Explicit` at the top of every code file. This will force you to declare all variables, and will avoid problems later. Don't think, just do it. Option. Explicit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this, but they both involve the `WorksheetExists` function. In this function you do not ever set the value for `WorksheetExists`, so it will always return the default value of `False`.

First way to fix is this:

```
Private Function WorksheetExists(ByVal workSheetName As String) As Boolean    

   For Each ws In Worksheets 
      If workSheetName = ws.name Then 
         WorksheetExists = True 
         Exit Function
      End If 
   Next ws 

End Function
```

Second is this:

```
Private Function WorksheetExists(ByVal workSheetName As String) As Boolean    
   IsExists = False 

   For Each ws In Worksheets 
      If workSheetName = ws.name Then 
         IsExists = True 
         GoTo ExitStep
      End If 
   Next ws 

ExitStep:
   WorksheetFunction = IsExists

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

the Worksheet Exists function needs to be updated like below:

```
Private Function WorksheetExists(ByVal workSheetName As String) As Boolean    
WorksheetExists = False 

For Each ws In Worksheets 
  If workSheetName = ws.name Then 
     WorksheetExists= True 
     Exit Function
  End If 
Next ws 

End Function
```

Comment: I was writing my answer at same time as you :)

Comment: So how accurate are the submission timestamps? Or does SO have an escalation policy of arm-wrestling to choose a winner?

Comment: It seems to go by Answered, Highest Upvotes, then last submitted from what i have noticed @PeterT